# Unable to load the requested class: Model, Error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, php-7.1

After update the codeigniter version 2.1.4 to 3.1.3 then show some error

**An Error Was Encountered**

Unable to load the requested class: Model

Also view some extra error for php version 7.1

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: 8192

Message: Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php

Line Number: 314

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: 8192

Message: Function mcrypt_decrypt() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php

Line Number: 323

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: 8192

Message: Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php

Line Number: 314

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: 8192

Message: Function mcrypt_decrypt() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php

Line Number: 323

Comment: Did you follow the CodeIgniter upgrade instructions?

Comment: please give me the upgrade instruction @Sparky

Comment: Don't be so lazy.  Everything is clearly posted in the documentation at CodeIgniter dot com.

Comment: i already follow the instruction, but i can't solve this problem, Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this post can help you : 
[Call to undefined function mcrypt_decrypt() - even when php5-mcrypt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872597/call-to-undefined-function-mcrypt-)
decrypt-even-when-php5-mcrypt-installed